# Select hidden <li></li> with python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I have so source html code:

```html
<div class="timezone" id="js-timezone">
  <span class="timezone__current">2:27 (GMT +2)</span>
  <ul class="timezone__list">
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"  onclick="set_timezone('+3');"><span>+3</span>Moscow, Riyadh</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="set_timezone('+4');"><span>+4</span>Muscat</a>     </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

It's hidden, when I move coursor to span class="timezone__current" show the menu.
Now i'm trying to click on "+3 GMT" with Python and Selenium

```
print ('Opening browser...')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = 'C:\geckodriver\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.betexplorer.com/next/soccer/")
search_timezone = 
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@class='timezone__list']")
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].setAttribute("onclick", "set_timezone(+3);")', search_timezone)
```

And nothing going on.

I've also tried:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = 'C:\geckodriver\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.betexplorer.com/next/soccer/")
search_timezone = 
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@class='timezone__list']")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element(search_timezone).perform()
select_timezone = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "+3 Moscow, Riyadh")))
select_timezone.click()
```

And there is TimeoutException

Please, help me with it, i'm going crazy

Answer (score -1):

Found this:

```
search_timezone = driver.find_element_by_class_name("timezone")
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element(search_timezone).perform()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
select_timezone = search_timezone.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')[3]
select_timezone.click()
```